How to find all cells related to specific values using only formulas in excel?
I have to find all values related to specific data from one table. Case is that data by which I have to search can appears more than once, but values will be always unique, do not appear more than once. The issue is more complicated, but there is no need to explain, I just can't deal with that part, cause I can't use a macro and can't use the filters. I has to be done that I write data in specific cell and under that cell, thanks to excel formula, I can see all related values line by line. Could you help me?

I've tried to use vlookup formula, I didn't worked. I think I can deal with index + match formula, but I stopped in a moment when I have to find the related values pointing a position -1 to first retrieved value. It seems that my solution is very complicated and maybe it is simplier version.

With 365 FILTER function can does it.

It would help to help you if you show your expected result instead of "formula showing ..."

@Ike Example is below, ie.
I point "data X", below it shows me related values from table

Try FILTER() function.
=FILTER(B1:B5,A1:A5=A9)

For Excel-2013 and later, could try AGGREGATE() in this way-
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$5,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($1:$5)/($A$1:$A$5=$A$9),ROW(1:1))),"")


